# custom control validator with same modification

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I did the same modification on 3 kind of BaseValidator. I search a way to remove the duplicate code.

I did the same code for RequiredFieldValidator , RegularExpressionValidator and CustomValidator

```
Public Class CustomValidator
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)

        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ControlToValidate) Then
                Dim ctv As Control = Me.FindControl(ControlToValidate)
                writer.AddAttribute("for", ctv.ClientID)
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

        MyBase.Render(writer)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property TagKey() As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag
        Get
            Return HtmlTextWriterTag.Label
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Extract the repeated code into a utility class and call it from the three places.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in this situation. maybe I can put a big part (trycatch) of the render function but Its not quite powerfull change. I was more looking for a parade like multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue you have with these exact classes; I wanted to add some additional features to the validation controls. The way I ended up sharing some common code was implementing my own classes that inherited from the validator classes and then implementing the shared logic in a utility class. I'm not familiar with VB, so please bear with the C# example.

```
public static class ValidationUtilities
{
    public static void AddFor(Control validationControl, string controlToValidate, HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlToValidate))
        {
            var ctv = validationControl.FindControl(controlToValidate);
            writer.AddAddtribute("for", ctv.ClientID);
        }
    } 
}

class MyRegularExpressionValidator : RegularExpressionValidator
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        ValidationUtilities.AddFor(this, ControlToValidate, writer);
    }
}

class MyRequiredFieldValidator : RequiredFieldValidator 
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        ValidationUtilities.AddFor(this, ControlToValidate, writer);
    }
}
```

You could make the argument that's more work than it's worth for not duplicating a small amount of code, but if you have a lot more, or your duplicated code is complex in some way, this is a way you can share it. Also, I made my utility class static, but there's no reason it couldn't be otherwise.

Comment: not the best way I was hopping, but its still shorter. could be so much beautiful if we can just have a second inheritance of "My" classes.